# How to disable SSH passphrase keychain saves in OS X Sierra

Tags: macos, keychain, ssh

I like having my SSH passphrase stored for the duration of my MacBook session, so that I don't have to keep entering it every time I SSH into a server, but when I restart my computer I want to have to enter it again (I don't want my passphrase encrypted and stored on disk in the keychain). This wasn't the case until I upgraded from Mountain Lion to Sierra; ever since then, it has been permanently storing my passphrase in my keychain. I can open the keychain preferences and delete my SSH passphrase, but the next time I SSH into a server and it prompts me for my passphrase, it is immediately added to the keychain again.

How can I get back to what I had with mountain lion, where my passphrase would be stored for the duration of my MacBook session, but then I would need to reenter it the next time I turn my MacBook on again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [a new option `UseKeychain` in Sierra](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html), which defaults to `yes` and which is a reason for this behavior. If you do not like that, edit the configuration in `~/.ssh/config` (or create this file):

```
UseKeychain no
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

The second option will tell the SSH agent to store the keys, which has the same result as if you had used `ssh-add` to enter your passphrase beforehand.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Will this allow me to still have the passphrase saved during my computer session so I don't have to enter it every time, or will this change so that I have to enter it every time?

Comment: You can try `AddKeysToAgent yes` option, which should do that. But give it a try. I dont have mac.